# Android /system/framework/*.jar files

Tags: android, adb

I did `ls -al /system/framework/` on my Android 5.0.1 phone via `adb shell`

I noticed about 95% of the `.jar` files there were 309 bytes. After pulling one such file using `adb pull` and unzipping them showed the `.jar` file only contained `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

Where is the actual `dex` code of these `jar` files. ?

P.S. My phone is not rooted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From Lollipop, due to ART, the framework files are in `/system/framework/arm/boot.oat` file.

Use 'java -jar [oat2dex.jar](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5/general/tool-deodex-tool-android-l-t2972025) boot boot.oat' and you will get a dex folder containing `framework.dex` and `framework-classes2.dex`.